# How to get an Key value pair from a array of objects in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Sample array of objects:

```
{"29": "DTE Queue", "30": "Services Reporting Sales", "31": "Services Reporting Ops", "41": "UPLOAD", "55": "Support Report"}.
```

I'm getting input from user as `'sup'`. Then output should be `{"55": "Support Report"}`.

```
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find((key) => object[key] === value);
}
```

Comment: Your _"sample array of objects"_ is one object, not an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the object to an array of entries, find the entry and convert it back to an object:

```js
const obj = {"29": "DTE Queue", "30": "Services Reporting Sales", "31": "Services Reporting Ops", "41": "UPLOAD", "55": "Support Report"};

function getObjectByValue(object, value) {
  try {
    return Object.fromEntries([Object.entries(object).find(([key, val]) => val.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Object not found');
    return {};
  }
}

console.log(getObjectByValue(obj, 'sup'));
console.log(getObjectByValue(obj, 'sup2'));
```

Comment: This will give error in `Object.fromEntries()` if the item is not found for that particular value

Comment: Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'unknown'. I'm getting this error for val.toLowerCase()

Comment: Thanks jabaa and ankit. I just did a modification by giving datatype object inside parameter. It worked like a gem :)

Comment: @DIMPLEPANDA `Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'unknown'`. That's a TypeScript error. You have to type the parameters.

Comment: when I search services Im getting 30: services reporting sales but I should also get 31:services reporting ops along with it. Any idea what shd I add?

Comment: @DIMPLEPANDA Please don't ask follow up questions in comments. You asked a specific question and I gave a correct answer. If you have a new question, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = {
  "29": "DTE Queue",
  "30": "Services Reporting Sales",
  "31": "Services Reporting Ops",
  "41": "UPLOAD",
  "55": "Support Report"
};

console.log(getKeyByValue(obj, 'sup'))

function getKeyByValue(obj, value) {
  const matchedEntry = Object.entries(obj).find(entry => entry[1].toLowerCase().match(value.toLowerCase()));

  return matchedEntry && Object.fromEntries([matchedEntry])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()` for the result you are expecting:

```js
const obj = {
  "29": "DTE Queue",
  "30": "Services Reporting Sales",
  "31": "Services Reporting Ops",
  "41": "UPLOAD",
  "55": "Support Report"
};

function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  const res = Object.entries(object).find((arr) => arr.includes(value));
  if (res) {
    return Object.fromEntries([res]);
  }
}

console.log(getKeyByValue(obj, 'Support Report'));
```

Comment: if I console res then I'm getting undefined. Also we should convert to lower case and compare right?

Comment: Share your code @DIMPLEPANDA

Comment: getKeyByValue(obj,value){
    console.log(obj,value);
    console.log(Object.keys(obj));
    console.log(Object.values(obj));
    try{
      return (<any>Object).fromEntries([Object.entries(obj).find(([key, val]) => val.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))]);
    }
    catch(err){
      console.error('Object not found');
      return {}
    }
   
    
  }